# Enable Tornado client debug log/mode

Tags: python, debugging, logging, tornado

How do I enable any debug log with Tornado **client**?

For the server case you simply pass Debug=true to the Application constructor (see [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html)). But what about the client?

From this [doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html?highlight=websocket_connect), under "Client-side support", it seems like the correct, and only?, way to create a client is to invoke the websocket_connect method. Are there any different ways to create a client?

Here is what I tried:

Pass:

```
--logging=debug --log-file-prefix=/var/log/tlog
```

on the command line and use

```
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

A file called tlog is created but it's always empty.

Setting:

```
define("debug", True)

access_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.access")
access_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application")
app_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
gen_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.general")
gen_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

in my code.

(See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952468/tornado-websocket-client-loosing-response-messages/43953743#43953743) for the specific problem I'm trying to debug and my current code)

Comment: The docs say "If you pass `debug=True` to the `Application` constructor, the app will be run in debug/development mode."

Comment: @JacobIRR Yes, I've seen that, but here I do not have an Application. I think the docs refer to the server part. Am I missing something? Can I create a client application too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Application(debug=True)` option doesn't have anything to do with debug logging. Logging is controlled by the `--logging` flag (if you use `parse_command_line()`), and `--logging=debug` sets it to the most verbose level. There are simply very few logging lines in the client-side websocket code; if you're seeing empty log files then you're just not hitting any of them. You can verify this by adding calls to `logging.debug()` to your own code after `parse_command_line`.